# looping throug divs and giving them id and then making them clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  am trying to make multiple div inside my loop display there own unique message when they are clicked.
But I can't get the code to work. what I am trying to do is... 
div1 = hello im div1, div2  = hello im div2.

The divs display on the page as they should but I can't get the click message to work.
Thanks in advance for any help or advice :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var idcontainer = "";
  var divs = "";
  var clickcontent;
  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    divs += `<div class="divs" id="div${i}">Test${i}</div>`;
    clickcontent += "Hello i am div" + i;
    idcontainer += "#div" + i;
  }
  console.log(idcontainer);

  $("#output").html(divs);
  $(idcontainer).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(clickcontent);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need id for that, just store content in data `attr` and show in click as below

```js
var idcontainer = '';
var divs = '';
var clickcontent
for(i=1;i < 5;i++){

  clickcontent = 'Hello i am div' + i;
  divs += `<div class="divs" id="div${i}" data-content="`+clickcontent+`">Test${i}</div>`;
  
idcontainer += '#div' + i;
}
   // console.log(divs)
$("#output").html(divs);

$('.divs').click(function (e) { 
  
  alert($(this).data('content'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select many divs you need to separate their ids by comma; now the `idcontainer` looks like this - `#div1#div2...`, so the jquery won't yield any element (check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to find out why). If you were to store their ids in an array like:

```js
var idcontainer = [];
var divs = '';
var clickcontent
for(i=1;i < 5;i++){

  clickcontent = 'Hello i am div' + i;
  divs += `<div class="divs" id="div${i}" data-content="`+clickcontent+`">Test${i}</div>`;

idcontainer.push('#div' + i);
}
```

And then use the jquery like this:

```js
$(idcontainer.join(', ')).click(function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(clickcontent)
});
```

This would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to generate divs dynamically and append to any tag you want, here I have appended to a body tag.

```
// Creating Divs and assign class by the name of "dynamicDiv"

for(i=1;i < 5;i++){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = `I am div ${i}`;
    div.className = 'dynamicDiv';
    $("body").append(div);
}

// Attaching click event for each generated div by using class name
$('.dynamicDiv').on('click', function () {

    alert($(this).text()); // Displaying the text of div

});
```